# Having text only appear on IE with conditional statements

Tags: internet-explorer, conditional-statements

Sorry if a similar question may have been posted else where, I've been searching every where and im still unable to find a proper solution to my issue.

What I'm trying to accomplish here is have a line of text appear for the user **ONLY!** on **IE 11**, at the top header box of my site. [so to the left of those two buttons a sentence should only appear for IE 11 users to be able to read, all else are in the clear.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVJBw.png)

Solutions ive been given and currently have in my code are `<!--[if IE 11]>
        <p> only IE 11 will see this </p>
        <![endif]-->`

which doesn't display anything on my site just when i open the element.

**or**

```
<!--[if !(IE)]><!--> i am not ie <!--<![endif]-->
```

this second one displays it on all browsers which is what I'm not trying to accomplish.

*Thank you in advance for any help!*

Answer (score 0):

Conditional comments only work [in IE 9 and below](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you want to show a message to IE 11 users, you probably need to use JavaScript to show it.